# How to get Kinvey BAse64 Encoded values for Rest Authentication Header

Tags: android, api, backend, kinvey, mbaas

When using Kinvey via Rest APIs, it is asking for a authentication header with two params seperated with space: First with Basic/Kinvey and second param is Base64 encoded string which I am assuming would be encoded string for my username:password or APPID:APPSECRET. I know these Ids and username/passwords but how to convert these to Base 64 Encoded string. I tried converting these strings to BAse64 string via online tools/websites but that string didnot worked for me.

I was tring with postman first to check if Rest API is working fine but everytime my API is failing with error saying about authentication error is not correct.

I want to use via rest method and not via Kinveys SDK. Can someone help me out in finding what to use in authentication header and how to encode it in required format.

Any help would be highly appreciated.. !!!

Answer (score 1):

> First with Basic/Kinvey and second param is Base64 encoded string
>   which I am assuming would be encoded string for my username:password
>   or APPID:APPSECRET.

That's not the correct assumption. You need to log in with your username+password to the /login API, and use the resulting Kinvey token for your data access.
http://devcenter.kinvey.com/rest/guides/users#login

I recommend that you do NOT use the REST API directly, but instead use the SDK for your specific platform. In each SDK, there are indeed "login" calls that make this process easier for you.

Comment: Will check on it.. Thanks